# Real-Time Stopwatch by signalR - MVC ASP.NET

Tags: model-view-controller, timer, signalr, real-time, stopwatch

I have created stopwatch by using javascript on ASP.NET MVC project, and I want to use SignalR with knockout or any other technique that can view stopwatch to all connected clients.
This is the code:

```
    <html>
<head>
<style>
#output{
width:120px;
height:25px;
background-color:#ccc;
border: 1px solid #999;}
</style>

<script>
var time = 0; 
var running = 0;

function startPause(){
if(running == 0){
running = 1;
increament();
document.getElementById("startPause").innerHTML = "Pause";
}
else{
running = 0;
document.getElementById("startPause").innerHTML = "Resume";
}
}

function reset(){
running = 0;
time = 0;
document.getElementById("startPause").innerHTML = "Start";
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "00:00:00";

}

function increament(){
if(running == 1){
setTimeout(function(){
time++;
var mins = Math.floor(time/10/60);`<html>
<head>
<style>
#output{
width:120px;
height:25px;
background-color:#ccc;
border: 1px solid #999;}
</style>

<script>
var time = 0; 
var running = 0;

function startPause(){
if(running == 0){
running = 1;
increament();
document.getElementById("startPause").innerHTML = "Pause";
}
else{
running = 0;
document.getElementById("startPause").innerHTML = "Resume";
}
}

function reset(){
running = 0;
time = 0;
document.getElementById("startPause").innerHTML = "Start";
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "00:00:00";

}

function increament(){
if(running == 1){
setTimeout(function(){
time++;
var mins = Math.floor(time/10/60);
var secs = Math.floor(time/10%60);
var tenths = time % 10;
if(mins<10){mins= "0" + mins;}
if(secs<10){secs= "0" + secs;}

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = mins + ":" + secs + ":" + "0" + tenths;
increament();
}, 100);}
}


</script>

</head>
<body>
<p id="output">00:00:00</p>
<div id="controls">
<button id="startPause" onclick="startPause()">Start</button>
<button id="startPause" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>


</div>

</body>
</html>`
var secs = Math.floor(time/10%60);
var tenths = time % 10;
if(mins<10){mins= "0" + mins;}
if(secs<10){secs= "0" + secs;}

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = mins + ":" + secs + ":" + "0" + tenths;
increament();
}, 100);}
}


</script>

</head>
<body>
<p id="output">00:00:00</p>
<div id="controls">
<button id="startPause" onclick="startPause()">Start</button>
<button id="startPause" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have applied many signalR projects, but all of them posting (pushing) data to all client, and I think this cannot help me in viewing stopwatch to all clients.

Comment: You need to call a hub method on the server and this method should push  the value to all clients.

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't work. Because it pushes the data as constant value, and I this not what I want. I want to view stopwatch while it's working. Thanks for your comment

Comment: SignalR pushes values not objects. RoaPush the value every half a second or so and broadcast ot to clients. Or broadcast information that a stopwatch has started, is paused or has stopped and to control stopwatches on other clients.